# How do I make mySQL timestamp field format using phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, datetime

Can someone tell me how/where I go to make my timestamp field appear a certain way every time I create a new record.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(new_ts, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM cartons_current
```

This works, but how do I make the field automatically do this with every new record?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT` doesn't change the format of the stored data at all, it just adjusts how MySQL gives you that data. You need to do `DATE_FORMAT` in any `SELECT` query against that table, or you can create a `VIEW` (essentially, a fake table using a `SELECT` query).